# Rails where() clause on model association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have an Account model which has_many Users.  Accounts have a boolean "active" column.  How can I get all Users that belong to "active" accounts?

```
@users_of_active_accounts = User.?
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want all the users of all the active accounts in a flat array?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to join the accounts table and merge appropriate Account scope:

```
User.joins(:account).merge(Account.where(:active => true))
```

Comment: You can also use a named scope if you have one, e.g. `User.joins(:account).merge(Account.active)`

Comment: @SimonPerepelitsa should it be `:accounts`?

Answer (score 97):

Try this:

```
User.joins(:account).where(:accounts => { :active => true })
```

Comment: A couple of notes that may also help: i) `.joins(:account)` :account should be singular or plural depending on the association (e.g. singular for has_one and plural for has_many), ii) `.where(:accounts..` here accounts is refering to the table, so will always be plural. Hope saves someone a minute or two.  (correct me if I'm wrong on any of this)

Answer (score 17):

Use a where clause in the Account model's association:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, -> {where(active: true)}
```

The other queries will work, but if you only always care about active users, filtering at the association level will properly encapsulate the filter and save you headaches in the future.

Update:

You can also specify 2 relations on the same table:

```
 class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
   has_many :active_users, -> {where(active: true)}, :class_name => 'User'
```

2nd Update:

After re-reading the question, I now see that my answer didn't answer the question. Here's my answer to the question:

```
User.where(account: Account.where(active: true))
```

3rd Update:
Here's an example User model that has an active_users attribute

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  def self.active
    where(account: Account.where(active: true))
  end
end
```

Doing it this way allows you to put it inline with other user queries:

```
User.active.where(created_at: (1.week.ago..0.day.ago)).count
```

Comment: In Modal how i can add order by also here
has_many :users, -> {where(active: true)}

Comment: You can add it directly after the where function: has_many :users, -> {where(active: true).order(:name)}. Basically any active record query can be put in that closure, but using variables can be tricky because of the scope. There is a way to pass in scope to be able to use variables in the association though. Not sure where the documentation is on that though.

Comment: I believe that 3rd update could be written as a scope. `scope :active, -> { where(account: Account.where(active: true)) }`

Comment: Thanks @evanthegrayt, I'm not that familiar with that part of rails. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Helpful article reviewing scopes: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/scopes-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

A gem that exists to do that: [activerecord_where_assoc](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc) (I'm the author)

With it, you can do what you want this way:

```
@users_of_active_accounts = User.where_assoc_exists(:account, active: true)
```

And if you have a scope on Account for active, you could call it this way:

```
@users_of_active_accounts = User.where_assoc_exists(:account, &:active)
```

So now, if you want, you can make a nice scope for this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account

  scope :active_account, -> { where_assoc_exists(:account, active: true) }
end

@users_of_active_accounts = User.active_account
```

Read more in the [documentation](https://maxlap.github.io/activerecord_where_assoc/ActiveRecordWhereAssoc/RelationReturningMethods.html). Here is an [introduction](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md) and [examples](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Account.includes(:users).where(active: true)
```

Comment: This returns accounts, not users